# unbound method must be called with instance as first argument

Tags: django

I'm working with django and i'm getting this error: "unbound method create() must be called with SocialUrl instance as first argument (got nothing instead)". I've read several answers to the same problem here but i'm not sure they are doing the same thing wrong as i am.

Here is the Model containing the method i'm trying to call:

```
from django.db import models

class SocialUrl(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def create():
    socialUrl = SocialUrl(code = generateCode())
    socialUrl.save()
    return socialUrl


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.code
```

and here is the method trying to call SocialUrl.create():

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from .general import generateCode
from .models import SocialUrl

def test(request):

socialUrl = SocialUrl.create()
#print(SocialUrl.objects.all())
return render(request, 'test.html', RequestContext(request, {"title": socialUrl.code}))
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/su/asdadsf

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'SocialUrl')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-    packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Coomba\SbrgCoomba\SocialUrl\views.py" in test
8.  socialUrl = SocialUrl.create()

Exception Type: TypeError at /su/asdadsf
Exception Value: unbound method create() must be called with SocialUrl instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class before calling a method on the class. Change your view to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from .general import generateCode
from .models import SocialUrl

def test(request):

socialUrl = SocialUrl()
socialUrl.create()
#print(SocialUrl.objects.all())
return render(request, 'test.html', RequestContext(request, {"title": socialUrl.code}))
```

Notice how you instantiate the object first (`socialUrl = SocialUrl()`) then you run create on the object you've instantiated. (`socialUrl.create()`).

However, I'm not sure your create method is going to work as you intend. What are you trying to accomplish with the `create` method?

EDIT to address comments:

I'm not familiar with Java static methods, but I think the standard way to what you want to do is as follows:

First, define your model as you've done. Note that I removed the create method.

```
from django.db import models

class SocialUrl(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.code
```

Then, in your views, instantiate a model and populate it with the attributes you want.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from .general import generateCode
from .models import SocialUrl

def test(request):

    my_code = generateCode()
    socialUrl = SocialUrl()
    socialUrl.code = my_code # Setting code attribute to the result of your generateCode function
    socialUrl.save() # Saves instance of SocialUrl to database.
    return render(request, 'test.html', RequestContext(request, {"title": socialUrl.code}))
```

Comment: I'm coming from a java environment so i suppose that's where i get confused. I want to in java terms create a static method which creates an instance of SocialUrl. Basically a constructor. I thought python metheods not containg self as parameter would act like static methods... hmm...

Comment: I've read some more after you helped me see my error. Is the @staticmethod decorator really the way to go if i want to create a static factory method? (Altho i should probobly stick to __init__ in this case...)

Comment: Added some above. Let me know if this addresses your problem. You may be able to use @staticmethod, but I think the standard way is to create an instance, set the attributes, and save it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to package the instantiation, autogenerated content and .save() in one method. The @staticmethod solved the problem but i'm not sure it's a good way to solve the problem...I want a method where the system requests a new SocialUrl and gets a prefilled entry.